# How do I look in GA4 to see if people who viewed one product eventually ended up buying something else?

Tags: google-analytics-4

HELP!

Our best performing facebook ad involves a photo of a product that we're now almost out of stock in. My partner wants to take that photo out of our ads, but I'm arguing to keep it, because it's driving site traffic, and people might end up finding something else to buy. How might I look up in GA4 to see if people who entered our site on that product page eventually ended up browsing or purchasing something else?

I tried searching page/screen class and I can see that people are entering on that page and many are also exiting on that page. What I'm not sure is if they eventually return to purchase.